# What are SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) supported browsers?

Tags: svg

I Need SVG supported browsers list and if SVG have any other issue in the real time. I am planning to use SVG in my project for graphic charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php

Comment: What about mobile support on SVG?

Comment: Opera Mini and Opera Mobile both support SVG, see http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2010/03/16/opera-standards-chart

Answer (score 1):

Can I use SVG ?

Compatibility table for support of SVG in desktop and mobile browsers.

[1. http://caniuse.com/svg](http://caniuse.com/svg)

[2. http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG](http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG)

Comment: I added link (2nd) for compatibility tables