# Why doesn't this SVG graphic scale in IE9 and 10 (preview)?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, svg, cross-browser

According to [IE website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410107.aspx) SVG is supported. And according to this answer too [What are SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) supported browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656162/what-are-svg-scalable-vector-graphics-supported-browsers/3656242#3656242)

http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/2UWNe/show/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 480 360"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="button_surface" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      x1="1" x2="1" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop stop-color="#434343" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="#000000" offset="0.67"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="virtual_light" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop stop-color="#EEEEEE" offset="0" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop stop-color="#EEEEEE" offset="0.4" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <!-- button content -->
  <rect x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15" width="150" height="80"
    fill="url(#button_surface)" stroke="#363636"/>

  <text x="30" y="55" fill="white"
    font-family="Tahoma" font-size="20" font-weight="500">
    SVG Button
  </text>

  <!-- vitual lighting effect -->
  <rect x="12" y="12" rx="15" ry="15" width="146" height="76"
    fill="url(#virtual_light)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-opacity="0.4"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the question you linked to is over a year old, and browsers have changed a lot in that time. That doesn't change the facts with regard to your question, but just to warn you to beware of old information when researching browser capabilities. A better place to look for up-to-date browser support info might be http://CanIUse.com/

Comment: but that said, the answer to the linked question does hint at the problem -- it shows a table with colours showing how well each browser supports SVG. You should note that the table row for IE9 has a *lot* of red in it. I don't have the time to go through it, but the short answer is that while IE9 does support SVG, it may not have 100% support for everything that SVG does.

Comment: Do you have an example of a browser it does scale in?  No scaling for me in Firefox either.

Comment: Actually it does scale, but the button image is less than a quarter of the size of the `viewBox` - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 19):

IE seems to be mishandling the missing [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute. You can get it to scale in IE by adding `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` as seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2UWNe/4/show

However, what IE is showing is not the correct behavior, and thus this change causes other browsers to behave differently than IE. (Microsoft, however, [believes that they support `preserveAspectRatio`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972114.aspx).)

I haven't looked deeply at your units or content bounding boxes. What effect are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

SVGs don't scale the same way as raster images like JPG, PNG, and GIF which have a clearly defined size.

You will need to resort to hacks to guarantee same display across browsers.

Try this:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 480 360" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 99.99%; height: 1px; overflow: visible; box-sizing: content-box; enable-background:new 0 0 381.1 381.1;" ... >
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2UWNe/82/)

[Learn more](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using percentages for height and width, as explained here (http://www.seowarp.com/blog/2011/06/svg-scaling-problems-in-ie9-and-other-browsers/).

> If the width and height are either defined as something as useless as 100% or if they aren’t defined at all, these browsers will make a guess as to what the dimensions ought to be based on the points and shapes defined in the body of the SVG file.

Change to `width=480` and `height=360` and you should be fine.

Comment: A problem with this is that it is necessary for mobile Safari to change the width and height to 100% in order for an SVG to resize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use viewport units. This way your SVG will scale according to the size of the window:

```
<svg width="100%" height="20vw" viewBox="0 0 150 150"> 
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="130" fill="#00ff00"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orikon/qy43fb0p/