# Extra space above and below SVG in IE11

Tags: css, svg

I have an issue where extra space appears above and below the svg when the browser resizes horizontally. It seems to work fine in Chrome though. Here is a working example:

This is what it looks like in chrome:

[image]

And this is in IE11:

[image]

To replicate the same issue, you need to resize the browser window horizontally.

How can I remove the extra space?

Here's the code I am using:

```js
function animateSVG(a){function f(b){b<0&&(b=0),b>100&&(b=100);var c=(100-b)/100*e;a[0].style.strokeDashoffset=c}var b=a.find(".circle_foreground"),c=a.data("percent"),d=b[0].getAttribute("r"),e=Math.PI*(2*d);a[0].style.strokeDashoffset=e,setTimeout(function(){f(c)},0),a.find(".circle_text").text(c+"%")}animateSVG($("#circle_ok")),animateSVG($("#circle_recommended")),animateSVG($("#circle_urgent")),animateSVG($("#circle_undefined"));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.circle {
  text-align: center;        
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
.circle_foreground {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgb(101, 159, 33);
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke-dasharray: 282.6; /* the circuference 3.14 x diameter */
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5s;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.circle_background {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.circle_text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  fill: #666;
}
.circle.recommended .circle_foreground {
  stroke: rgb(255, 161, 0);
}
.circle.urgent .circle_foreground {
  stroke: rgb(255, 56, 0);
}
.circle.undefined .circle_foreground {
  stroke: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="circle ok" id="circle_ok" data-percent="44">
    <svg version="1.1" class="circle_container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <text class="circle_text" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="55"></text>
      <circle class="circle_background" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
      <circle class="circle_foreground" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
    </svg>
    <div>Ok</div>
  </div>

  <div class="circle recommended" id="circle_recommended" data-percent="16">
    <svg version="1.1" class="circle_container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <text class="circle_text" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="55"></text>
      <circle class="circle_background" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
      <circle class="circle_foreground" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
    </svg>
    <div>Recommended</div>
  </div>

  <div class="circle urgent" id="circle_urgent" data-percent="27">
    <svg version="1.1" class="circle_container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <text class="circle_text" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="55"></text>
      <circle class="circle_background" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
      <circle class="circle_foreground" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
    </svg>
    <div>Urgent</div>
  </div>

  <div class="circle undefined" id="circle_undefined" data-percent="13">
    <svg version="1.1" class="circle_container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <text class="circle_text" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="55"></text>
      <circle class="circle_background" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
      <circle class="circle_foreground" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
    </svg>
    <div>Not Set</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is likely that this is an issue with flexbox. IE 11 is known for its many bugs with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it happens if I just float the items left and set the width to 25%.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711641/why-doesnt-this-svg-graphic-scale-in-ie9-and-10-preview) helps.